# Tranfer QR Code Into a MySql Database

Tags: android, mysql, database, qr-code

I've been trying to figure out what's the easiest way of putting a scanned QR text file into a MySql Databse. What I would the application to do is scan the QR code with a mobile device and then save the scanned image into a file that would then be added into a MySql Driven Database. Is there an app that would give me the groundwork for this kind of project? Any guidance is highly appreciated!

Comment: Do you need to save the actual image or just its contents? It may be easier to save the scanned data then use a library like zxing to generate the QR code again using the saved data.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use [ZXing app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android). It it is installed just open the flowing url:

```
http://zxing.appspot.com/scan?ret=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fproducts%2F%7BCODE%7D%2Fdescription&SCAN_FORMATS=QR_CODE
```

This url will open the page http://example.com/procucts/ followed by the scanned QR code content. The paremeter `SCAN_FORMATS` will avoid that normal 1D barcodes will be accepted.

See also the full explanation on the [ZXing documentation](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningFromWebPages). Please note that the user will just see a normal webpage if the ZXing app is not installed.