# how create QR code using J2EE?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jakarta-ee, qr-code

I am developing a project that contains the user data such as name, address, phone and email. I would like a QR code was generated with this data and stored in the database along with the data for each user. 
Something like: [enter link description here](http://blog.trycontechnologi.netdna-cdn.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/qr-ocdes-in-india-bms.png?8d075d)

Anyone have any idea how I can do this using Java web?
Thanks.

Comment: I guess your question is too generic.... IMHO you should provide more details

Comment: You're right. I'm developing a project that contains the data of users, but I need a QR code to be generated starting such data.

Comment: Please provide more information. Such as a code sample of what you've tried already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating QR codes in Java is not hard. There is the excellent z[ebra crossing library](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) for that. The resulting image can be stored as blob in Mysql or you could use the input parameters and gernerate the image on the fly. There is a question on SO dealing with storing QR codes in mysql [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364703/tranfer-qr-code-into-a-mysql-database).